# PDO queries printing more than what I want

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Beginner here in PDO. I'm trying to print a table in a filtered way, where only the articles "artigo" should be displayed if they are type (tipo) 2. But still prints some empty DIVs. Am I missing something here?

```
$registos_por_pagina = 10;
$result_total_registos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artigo_categoria a_c INNER JOIN artigo a ON a.id = a_c.artigo WHERE a_c.categoria = :id AND a.estado = 1");
$result_total_registos->execute(array('id' => $id));
$total_registos = $result_total_registos->rowCount();
$result_registo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artigo_categoria a_c INNER JOIN artigo a ON a.id = a_c.artigo WHERE a_c.categoria = :id AND a.estado = 1 ORDER BY artigo DESC LIMIT 0, :registos_por_pagina");
$result_registo->execute(array('id' => $id, 'registos_por_pagina' => $registos_por_pagina));
$contador = 1;

 while ($row_registo = $result_registo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  $result_artigo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM artigo WHERE id = :artigo and tipo = 2"); //Não está a ordernar
  $result_artigo->execute(['artigo' => $row_registo['artigo']]);
  $row_artigo = $result_artigo->fetch();

  if ($contador==1 || $contador==2) {
    echo '<div class="artigo-fotografia-autor">
      <img src="backoffice/utilizadores/'.$row_artigo['autor'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row_artigo['autor'].'">
      <h4 class="destaque-titulo-pequeno mt-10">'.$row_artigo['titulo'].'</h4>
    </div>';
  } else {
    echo '<div class="artigo-fotografia-autor">
      <img src="backoffice/utilizadores/'.$row_artigo['autor'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row_artigo['autor'].'">
      <h4 class="destaque-titulo-pequeno mt-10">'.$row_artigo['titulo'].'</h4>
    </div>';
  }
  $contador++;
}
```

Here's what the DB looks like [image]

Comment: Well you might get a blank if the SELECT * FROM artigo... doesn't match any rows. e.g. for ID 10694, the tipo is 1, so the query won't return anything because it only selects rows where tipo = 2. (You should get some warnings in that case about undefined variables, they may be in your logs, if you've got PHP configured to log errors and warnings to a file).

Comment: I don't know the complexity of the first query that doesn't show, but are you sure you can't use a `JOIN LEFT` directly to get the value you need?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I edited the code with a few more queries that might be relevant

Comment: @ADyson I can print every entry in the database, if I only do "SELECT * FROM artigo WHERE id = :artigo". The problem is when I try to show only the ones that are "tipo = 2", as far as I know, it should work as is, but I might be missing something

Comment: Why should it work as-is? I already pointed out a piece of data which will be omitted by that because it has tipo=1. Therefore when the outer loop comes to process the for with ID 10694, the inner query will return nothing and so you won't see anything in the div.

Comment: Maybe you need to put that constraint on the outer query too so it never tries to process that ID at all?? I don't know. You have explained the problem but it's unclear what the actual business requirement is.

Comment: But also... the same data should be in `$row_registo` already, I don't know why you even need the extra query inside the while loop.